# Modify some bytes in a binary file in C

Tags: c, file, byte

Is there any way to change the value of a single byte in a binary file? I know that if you open the file in `r+b` mode, the cursor is positioned at the beginning of the existing file and anything you write in that file will overwrite the existing content.

But I want to change only 1 byte, for instance, in a file. I guess you could copy the content of the file that should not be modified and insert the desired value at the right place, but I wonder if there is any other way.

An example of what I would like to achieve:
Change 3rd byte to 67

Initial file:

```
00 2F 71 73 76 95
```

File content after write:

```
00 2F 67 73 76 95
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `fseek()` to position the **file-pointer** and then write out 1 byte:

```
// fseek example
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen("example.txt", "wb");
    fputs("This is an apple.", pFile);
    fseek(pFile, 9, SEEK_SET);
    fputs(" sam", pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

For an **existing file** and only changing 1 char:

```
FILE * pFile;
char c = 'a';

pFile = fopen("example.txt", "r+b");

if (pFile != NULL) {
    fseek(pFile, 2, SEEK_SET);
    fputc(c, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: So if I do `fseek(file, 3, SEEK_SET);` and then fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(char), 1, file);` and buffer holds the value 67, that will get the things done as I want?

Comment: Yes, but you could also use fputc(). And your 'file' in fseek() will need to be a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`fseek`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm) to move to a position in a file:

```
FILE *f = fopen( "file.name", "r+b" );
fseek( f, 3, SEEK_SET ); // move to offest 3 from begin of file
unsigned char newByte = 0x67;
fwrite( &newByte, sizeof( newByte ), 1, f );
fclose( f );
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that after doing something like this the file would hold just `00 2F 67`

Comment: @Gernot1976 note that `sizeof( unsigned char )` is `1` by definition, it would be better to use this to match any change in the variable type written, for example `sizeof newbyte`