# Modify the binary code of a file in C

Tags: c, io, binary

So, I have a C program where I am trying to save the binary code from a file that the user specifies. For example, if a user inputs a .txt or a .jpeg, or a .pdf, or whatever file extension they have, then I will be able to gather the binary code of the file. The catch is that the file will not be exclusively a .bin.

This is very specific to a project I am trying to make, so I don't see any documentation on how to achieve this. I believe this is achievable because technically every file is in binary, so, especially in C, this should be possible.

So far I have experimented by using `fopen` with an `rb` argument: `file = fopen(filename, "rb");` because I am trying to modify the binary specifically. And i'm trying to gather the binary by using `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);` which should traverse the file.

I am coming from a Python/Java background, so any guidance or help is appreciated.

My question is what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473625/modify-some-bytes-in-a-binary-file-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to draw a distinction where there isn't any- all files are binary.  Using `fopen` is the right approach- this opens the file for reading/writing by creating a file descriptor.  `fseek`, however, is not what you are looking for- this moves the file pointer without actually doing anything (ie it doesn't read the file).  What I think you are actually looking for is `fread` and `fwrite`, which actually manipulate the file binary.

You should [read more](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) about how file IO is done in C, and come back if you have **specific** questions about how to do this.